# XSLT - How to split each element based on a delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt

My input will be as follows in xml

```
abc(123)def(456)ghi(789)jkl(098)mno(765)
```

Can someone please let me know how to split the about input line using xslt based on a particular delimiter ')' so that the output looks as follows .
After closed parenthesis delimiter should be ';'

```
abc(123);def(456);ghi(789);jkl(098);mno(765)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't really look like you're splitting anything, another XSLT 2.0 option is to just `replace()`...

**XML Input**

```
<test>abc(123)def(456)ghi(789)jkl(098)mno(765)</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'\)',');')"/>
      <!-- 
        Instead of replace(), you could also use tokenize()/string-join():
         <xsl:value-of select="string-join(tokenize(.,'\)'),');')"/>
        or even tokenize() with the separator attribute:
         <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,'\)')" separator=");"/>
      -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<test>abc(123);def(456);ghi(789);jkl(098);mno(765);</test>
```

If you need to use XSLT 1.0 and don't want/can't use extension functions, you can use a recursive template call:

**XSLT 1.0** (Same input/output as above.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="addSeparator">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="addSeparator">
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($input,')')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($input,')'),')',$sep)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
      <xsl:call-template name="addSeparator">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remaining"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="sep" select="$sep"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```